# Получить данные с календаря

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите пожалуйста можно ли получить данные после того как пользователь выберет дату, посредством js для того, чтобы отправить запрос через ajax для получения свободных свободных окон времени?

То есть, как только пользователь выберет дату можно было подгрузить свободные окошки для записи?

```
$( function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd",
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: "+10D",
  monthNames : ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'],
    dayNamesMin : ['Вс','Пн','Вт','Ср','Чт','Пт','Сб'], });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, то можно конечно, иначе зачем этот datepicker нужен :)

Для этого используется метод `getDate()`: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate

Или ты имеешь ввиду получить дату в момент клика по дате? Тогда код такой:

```
`$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { 
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
    }
});`
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147108/getting-value-from-jquery-datepicker